# disable saturday using jquery-ui-datepicker with contact form 7

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, jquery-ui-datepicker, contact-form-7

Hello i'm trying to disable all saturdays from my calendar 
the calendar is contact form 7 and its using  jquery-ui-datepicker 
this is my short code :

```
[date* your-date date-479 id:datepiicker min:today placeholder "date de reservation*" ]
```

and this is my Jquery code :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

$("#datepiicker").datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
        var day = date.getDay();
        return [(day != 6), ''];
    }
});

});
```

but its not working

```js
$("#datepiicker").datepicker({
  beforeShowDay: function(date) {
    var day = date.getDay();
    return [(day != 6), ''];
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<input type="date" id="datepiicker" />
```

Comment: no its saturday

Comment: Ohh but I know you title said sunday. Do you get any errors? Also how is your "short code" relevant to the question? Are you using it or ?

Comment: yes i'm using this shortcode in my wordpress website i can see the calendar but the user can select saturday ( and it was a mistak in the title sorry ) also there is no errors in the console

Comment: Your code is working correctly - as you can see from the snippet I edited in to the question. Check the console in your local version for errors, and ensure you've added all necessary JS libraries to the page properly.

Comment: Not 100% related to this but why do you have a ready function inside another ready function? in your custom.js file

Comment: even when i remove the double ready function its not working

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen i think its because my input is type date not texte

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan my input is type date not type texte so if you click on the calendar icon in the snippet bellow you can see that its not working at all

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan yes but there is another callendar displey when you click on the calendar icon and the saturday is clickable in this one you can try

Comment: That's because its showing the standard HTML calendar because you're using the `type="date"` input. Don't use that type of input. Just use `type="text"` as the [documentation](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) tells you to.

Comment: that's the prolem i'm using the contact form 7 plugin and i can't do type texte because in this case it give me just a text field not date even if i add the datepiicker id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution in my case is to check the day. If it's saturday i can reset the value and tell the user to pick something else using alert.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

const picker = document.getElementById('datepiicker');
picker.addEventListener('input', function(e){
  var day = new Date(this.value).getUTCDay();
  if([6].includes(day)){
    e.preventDefault();
    this.value = '';
    alert("This day is not available ");
  }
});
});
```